# Search and Edit Records of custom object with Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, class

i have a vf page and a custom controller . i have fields on page to create a new record in object but  i also want to search a particular record in object and want to edit or update its feilds...... can anyone help me........

vf page

```
<apex:page controller="showdetail" tabStyle="opd__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:pageblock >
              <apex:form >


   <!--  <apex:selectList value="{!objectselection}" size="1" multiselect="false" onselect="">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!selection}" > <apex:commandButton action="{!main}" value="Show!"/>   </apex:selectOptions>
            </apex:selectList>             -->




         <apex:selectList value="{!objectselection}" size="1" multiselect="false" onselect="">
           <apex:selectOption itemValue="none" itemlabel="--none--"></apex:selectOption>
           <apex:selectOption itemValue="ipd" itemlabel="ipd"></apex:selectOption>
           <apex:selectOption itemValue="opd" itemlabel="opd"></apex:selectOption>
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!find}"/>
            </apex:selectList> 

               <style>
               .buttonStyle { width:5%;  text-align:center; padding-top:4px; }
               </style>

               <apex:outputPanel id="mypannel">
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!bmypannel}">

                                <!-- data fetch -->

         <!--     <apex:inputtext id="searchTextBox" value="{!searchText}"> <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search"/></apex:inputtext>  -->


              <apex:pageBlockSection title="IPD FORM" columns="3"> 
              <!--        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!val}" var="v"> -->
                          <apex:inputField value="{!val.Name}"/>
                          <apex:inputField value="{!val.Patient_name__c}"/>
                          <apex:inputField value="{!val.Age__c}"/>
                          <apex:inputField value="{!val.Father_name__c}"/>
                          <apex:inputField value="{!val.phone_no__c}"/>
                          <br> </br>
                          </apex:pageBlockSection>
                          <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" styleClass="buttonStyle" />
                          <apex:commandButton action="{!saveandnew}" value="Save and New" style="width:15%"/>
                           <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="cancel" styleClass="buttonStyle"/>
                      <!-- </apex:pageBlockTable> -->

            <!-- </apex:pageBlockSection> -->



                            </apex:outputPanel>

                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!vmypannel}">

                                    <apex:pageBlockSection title="OPD FORM" columns="3">

                                    <apex:inputField value="{!pdf.Name}"/>
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!pdf.address__c}"/>
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!pdf.country__c}"/>
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!pdf.PIN__c}"/>
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!pdf.state__c}"/>
                                    <br></br>
                                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!myaction}" styleClass="buttonStyle"/>
                                    <apex:commandButton value="Save and New" action="{!newaction}" style="width:15%"/>
                                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancelaction}" styleClass="buttonStyle"/>


                                                                        </apex:outputPanel>
                                                                                        </apex:outputPanel>





   </apex:form>
      </apex:pageblock>   
</apex:page>
```

apex class

```
public with sharing class showdetail { public string objectselection{get;set;}  public Boolean bmypannel{get;set;} public Boolean vmypannel{get;set;} public ipd__c val{get;set;} public opd__c pdf{get;set;} public string searchText{get;set;} public List<ipd__c> src{get;set;} ApexPages.Action saveAction = new ApexPages.Action('{!save}');

                public showdetail() {
                bmypannel = false;
                vmypannel = false;
                val = new ipd__c();
                pdf = new opd__c();
            }
    // search button




 public PageReference  search(){  
     String searchquery= 'SELECT Name,Patient_name__c,Father_name__c,Age__c,phone_no__c FROM ipd__c' + 'where Name like \'%'+searchText+'%\' order by Name'; 
     src= Database.query(searchquery);  
     return null;    }  

    // search button





            // public List<SelectOption> getselection()   {
       // List<SelectOption> selection= new List<SelectOption>();
       // selection.add(new selectoption('','-None-'));
       // selection.add(new selectoption('ipd','ipd'));
       // selection.add(new selectoption('opd','opd'));


       // return selection;
         //   }

           // public void main() {
       // if (objectselection== 'ipd') {
       // bmypannel = true;
       // vmypannel = false;
       // } else if (objectselection== 'opd'){
       // vmypannel = true;
       // bmypannel = false;
       // } else {
       // vmypannel = false;
       // bmypannel = false;
        // }
         // }

         public void find()  {
         if (objectselection == 'ipd' )    {
         bmypannel = true;
         vmypannel = false;    }
         else if (objectselection == 'opd') {
         vmypannel = true;
         bmypannel = false;
         } else {
         vmypannel = false;
         bmypannel = false;
         }    }


             public pageReference saveandnew()
    {
        insert this.val;
        pageReference Pagekl = new pageReference('/apex/practice?');
        pagekl.setRedirect(true);
        return pagekl; } 

            public pageReference save() {
    insert this.val;

    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/picklist?');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;   

}

            public pageReference cancel()
             {
                pageReference Page = new pageReference('/apex/practice?');
                        page.setRedirect(true);
                        return page; }

                public pageReference myaction() {
    insert this.pdf;

    PageReference pageRe = new PageReference('/apex/picklist?');
    pageRe.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRe; }

         public pageReference newaction()
    {
        insert this.pdf;
        pageReference Pagereload = new pageReference('/apex/practice?');
        pagereload.setRedirect(true);
        return pagereload;
        }

          public pageReference cancelaction()
             {
                pageReference Paged = new pageReference('/apex/practice?');
                        paged.setRedirect(true);
                        return paged; }    }
```